# Downloaded local .xlsx file won't open (AngularJS and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, download, frontend

I created a button to download test-report.xlsx that sits on the frontend. A file with the correct name will download, however, it will not open. The normal file is about 10MB, but the file after downloading it via the button is about 6MB.

Do I need to do something to the xlsx file when downloading it?

EDIT: When clicking on the file I get the following error from Numbers:

`"test-report.xlsx” can’t be opened right now. Numbers couldn’t read the file.`

My code:

```
<md-button target="_self" href="files/test-report.xlsx" download="test-report.xlsx">
  Download Report
</md-button>
```

Comment: What **specifically** does *will not open* mean? *will not open* is extremely vague and meaningless. You need to provide a **specific** problem description. In what way does it *not open*? How are you trying to open it? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the **exact** error message you see? If you want help, explain the actual problem you're having so we can understand it.

Comment: Thanks! Added the error message I receive. 

``"test-report.xlsx” can’t be opened right now. Numbers couldn’t read the file.``

Comment: There might be multiple reasons why the file might not open. Could be angular, numbers or something else. Can you add snippet for the directive?or add plunkr?So it is easier to narrow down